# ASP.NET Core could not load file or assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, aws-sdk

I created a ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API. (called project A).

I have reference to another project. (project B).
Project B has a reference to AWS.SDK.

When I run my WebAPI (Project A) and init class from Project B I get an exception:
"Could not load file or assembly AWS.SDK"

I checked folder: bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0 and AWS.SDK dll exists.

When I add the Nuget reference of AWS.SDK to Project A, all working.
The nuget reference has added to a folder: .nuget/packages/AWS.SDK/

Even more, I did the same scenario but instead project A of type .NET Core I created project A of type .NET Framework 4.5 and all working without to install the nuget AWS.SDK in root project (Project A).

I try to understand why I get "Could not load file assembly" exception even though the aws.sdk dll exists in bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0 folder?

Comment: I can only assume that the `AWS.SDK` you are installing is not a .NETCore compatible library.

Comment: @ethane the AWS.SDK is compatible with .net core (AWS.SDK.CloudWatch v3.3.5.3)

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot of your assembly's references?

Comment: "I checked folder: bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0 and AWS.SDK dll exists." which bin is that? Project A or B?